# Sonar project-properties file

Tags: sonarqube

I am using OCLint on an Objective C project to obtain a SonarQube profile.

Now my IOS Objective C project contains a src directory with multiple sub src directories. In my `sonar-project.properties` file there is a following entry

```
sonar.sources=MySrcFolder/
```

Now within this src folder i want to run the sonar profile on multiple subfolders and exclude some third party src folders. Can anyone help me with this ? As it stands now, sonar runs the profile on all src in any of the above folders subfolders ?

Answer (score 30):

You can do it only with `sonar.sources` property or with the `sonar.exclusions` and `sonar.inclusions` properties.

Example:

```
MySrcFolder
    src1
    src2
    src3
    src4
```

If you want to analyze only `src1` and `src3` then,

1) `sonar.sources=MySrcFolder/src1,MySrcFolder/src3`

OR

2)

```
sonar.sources=MySrcFolder
sonar.exclusions=src2/**,src4/**
```

OR

3)

```
sonar.sources=MySrcFolder
sonar.inclusions=src1/**,src3/**
```

Following rules are applied in the `exclusions` and `inclusions` properties:

```
*   Match zero or more characters
**  Match zero or more directories
?   Match a single character
file:   Prefix to define a pattern based on absolute path
```

For more details: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Comment: @L.Langó Can we use inclusions and exclusions together? Or we can only use one of them at a time?

Comment: @kav12345 I can only guess, I did not use this feature for a long time. Probably you can, but I do not know which one has the higher priority. Usually exclusions are stronger.

Answer (score 2):

Add below lines to **sonar-scanner-v.x.x/conf/sonar-scanner.properties** file. Use
Comma-separated paths to analysis multiple modules or projects.

```
sonar.sources= mainDir/subDir/src, mainDir/subDir/subDir/src,...
```

**Or**

```
Set base directory with **sonar.projectBaseDir** param.
```

Thanks to the param, you can give relative path to sonar.sources's params.

**Then**

Run sonar-scanner.bat file in  mainDir or root in directory of above sources.